# Do I need to setup a "zone" for every domain name that is visible to the outside world?

Tags: dns, bind, domain-server

I have a quick question. I just setup DNS on one of our Ubuntu servers using Bind9. Now my question is do we need to setup a "zone" for every domain name that is visible to the outside world? Or is there another option? What are the best practices for setting up different domains in Bind9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little while after I posted this message I found the answer posted in the Ubuntu forum. :) For every top level domain a "zone" does in fact need to be created. Here is the URL for anyone interested:

[http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:ZVsbIZMfxPoJ:ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=699931%20configure%20multiple%20domains%20in%20bind9&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&source=www.google.com](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aZVsbIZMfxPoJ%3aubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=699931%20configure%20multiple%20domains%20in%20bind9&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&source=www.google.com)